# matplotlib - plot merged dataframe with group bar

Tags: matplotlib

I try to plot a grouped bar chart from a merged dataframe. below code the bar is stacked, how can I put it side by side just like a grouped bar chart?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key':  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value':[ 10  ,6,   6,   8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key':  ['B', 'D', 'A', 'F'],
    'value':[ 3,   5,   5,  7]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['key'])
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

b1 = ax.bar(df3['key'],df3['value_x'])
b2 = ax.bar(df3['key'],df3['value_y'])

pngname = "demo.png"
fig.savefig(pngname, dpi=fig.dpi)
print("[[./%s]]"%(pngname))
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: `df3.plot.bar(x='key', ax=ax, rot=0, xlabel='')`?

Comment: It should be `ax = df3.plot(kind='bar', x='key', rot=0, xlabel='', figsize=(12, 8))` as it returns an `axes`, and it's not being plotted in a subplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the x axis data is the same, in your case it aren't numbers, it are the keys: "A", "B", "C". So matplotlib stacks them one onto another.

There's a simple way around it, as some tutorials online show https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-grouped-bar-plot-in-matplotlib/.

So, what you do is basically enumerate the keys, i.e. A=1, B=2, C=3. After this, choose your desired bar width, I chose 0.4 for example. And now, shift one group of bars to the left by *bar_width/2*, and shift the other one to the right by *bar_width/2*.

Perhaps the code explains it better than I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key':  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value':[ 10  ,6,   6,   8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key':  ['B', 'D', 'A', 'F'],
    'value':[ 3,   5,   5,  7]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['key'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

# modifications
x = np.arange(len(df3['key']))  # enumerate the keys
bar_width = 0.4  # choose bar length

b1 = ax.bar(x - bar_width/2,df3['value_x'], width=bar_width, label='value_x')  # shift x values left
b2 = ax.bar(x + bar_width/2,df3['value_y'], width=bar_width, label='value_y')  # shift x values right
plt.xticks(x, df3['key'])  # replace x axis ticks with keys from df3.
plt.legend(['value_x', 'value_y']) 
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Result of running the code from above.]